# Is the product of the slopes of $2$ perpendicular lines $-1$?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

If I have $2$ lines$AB$ and $PQ$ perpendicular to each other drawn on a graph- then will **the slope of $AB$ times the slope of $PQ$ be equal to $-1$**?

i.e
$$
     [(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)] \times [(b2-b1)/(a2-a1)]  = -1 ?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is so. A small trigonometrical proof will be like this:

$$\tan( \theta + \frac{\pi}{2} ) = - \cot {\theta} = - \frac{1}{\tan{\theta}}$$

Comment: So long as neither line is vertical, of course.

Comment: @CameronBuie I see what you did there.